# How to hide java field in json?

Tags: java, json

How can I not show field in Json? I tried @JsonIgnore, but it doesn't work for me. I need this field only to use in my code, but not to show in json. How can I do it?

Code:

```
@Override
public final BigDecimal getPrice() {
    if (best != null) {
        return packet.Price();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What are your dependencies and import package using @JsonIgnore? Can you put here editing the question? The main problem of @JsonIgnore is import a wrong package.

Comment: There are many JSON libraries for Java. If you want answer related to specific library please specify it in your question.

Comment: How is the code relevant to the question?

Comment: For example, https://www.javaguides.net/2019/04/jackson-ignore-fields-or-properties-on-serialization.html they give complete working examples. Build, run, and output. Can you do the same thing? Show the complete class that you serialize and the resulting JSON.

Comment: Have you set @JsonIgnore annotation on the variable declaration?  ```@JsonIgnore private String price```

Answer (score 0):

The first option is using `@JsonIgnore`.
To use it correctly, you need to put the dependency that you are using and the import.

Example that works:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@JsonIgnore
public BigDecimal getPrice(){
}
```

Using the dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

A **common problem** is when the project has two `Jackson` dependencies.

In this case, sometimes you need to put this follow instead the first:

```java
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
```

But **you need to verify why the project is using two dependencies** of the same project and remove one whether is your situation.

Comment: I added comment with my code. Please check it. It still doesn't work. Maybe you will find problem.